# Using Gson, how can I serialize nulls in maps but not in other classes?

Tags: java, json, gson

Using Gson, I want to be able to serialize nulls in `Map`s but not in other classes. I.e., if I have a class like this:

```java
public class Foo {
  @SerializedName("bar")
  Bar bar;

  @SerializedName("my_map")
  Map<String, Object> myMap;
}
```

If the `bar` field is null and `myMap` contains one entry `"key" -> null`, I want the resulting JSON string to be:

```
{
  "my_map": {
    "key": null,
  }
}
```

However, I need this to work in a very generic manner: I have a lot of classes with a complex hierarchy and classes and containers may be deeply nested.

I have tried the following:

- using `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()`. This doesn't work because it serializes all null values.
- using a `TypeAdapterFactory`. This almost works, but I can't find a way to reuse Gson's default `MapTypeAdapter` with a serialization context where `serializeNulls = true`. `MapTypeAdapter` is `final` so I cannot subclass it. I don't want to write a `TypeAdapter` from scratch to serialize maps.

I feel like there's a simple solution that I'm missing. Any help appreciated.

Comment: do you want to ignore `null` fields during serialization ? then try without this `.serializeNulls()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to notice that `SerializeNulls` feature we can set on `com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter` instance directly. So, let's implement custom `com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory` which forces always this feature for `Map` instances:

```
class ForceNullsForMapTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    public final <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        if (Map.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType())) {
            final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
            return createCustomTypeAdapter(delegate);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private <T> TypeAdapter<T> createCustomTypeAdapter(TypeAdapter<T> delegate) {
        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                final boolean serializeNulls = out.getSerializeNulls();
                try {
                    out.setSerializeNulls(true);
                    delegate.write(out, value);
                } finally {
                    out.setSerializeNulls(serializeNulls);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                return delegate.read(in);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Simple usage:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class GsonApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("nullKey", null);
        map.put("other", "Not Null!");

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setMyMap(map);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ForceNullsForMapTypeAdapterFactory())
                .create();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(foo));
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "my_map": {
    "nullKey": null,
    "other": "Not Null!"
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I think this is exactly what I was looking for. `getDelegateAdapter()` was the missing piece of the puzzle. Thanks so much!